# RSS Feed Web Part Stopped Working - SharePoint Online 2013 - Internal Server Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, rss

I am still fairly new to SharePoint and do not have much development experience in it.  We are using SharePoint Online 2013.  I've checked the forums for similar posts but can't seem to find any answers.

We have an rss feed that shows calendar events in the RSS Feed Web Part viewer and we now receive this error.

"ProtocolError occured trying to complete the request.  The server returneda status code of:  InternalServerError and the status description is: "Internal Server Error"

Other RSS Feeds are working fine in the webpart. (cnn/msn/yahoo/etc.)

Here is the link to our RSS Feed that is not working:

http://www.shorelinewa.gov/Home/Components/RssFeeds/RssFeed/View?id=3

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, it's driving me mad.

Thank you.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link you provided it looks like that it is not a valid rss feed hence the error. You may have the wrong link or they may have made a change in their systems which has broken their RSS feed.

Best bet is to contact them and let them know about the malformed RSS feed/ confirm that the above is indeed the proper link to their RSS feed.

Comment: Roland,  that's what I was thinking as well.  This link is provided to us from our External site host, they said that they haven't changed anything and kind of just left me in the dark for myself.  What do you think I could say/tell them to have them "fix" this or create a useable RSS Link?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarkApolinar  What you tell them is up to you, however if you provide shoreline with a link to another rss so that they can see the difference perhaps then they may explain why theirs is different.
If you think the answer is correct please mark it as correct to help 'close' this question.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I gave them a call and explained to them the situation.  They put in a ticket and will hopefully get back to me tomorrow, I will definitely update the topic as more information comes.  I think I may just use the Data View Web Part, Content Query, or XML view web parts.  I will try those out tomorrow as alternatives.